# CSV File upload issue

Tags: php

I am trying to upload CSV file using file uploader control in php, If the file size is more that 10 MB its not getting uploaded its just hangs the page execution. I have set

> ini_set( "upload_max_filesize", "50M" );  ini_set( "post_max_size",
>   "50M" );

on the page, still don't have any luck for me.If I upload file up to 8 MB its working fine.I am confused about why the isue is still there event I have did setting related to file size upload on same page. Please help me.

Thanks in advance,

Following is my PHP code

```
<?php

  set_time_limit(0); ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set( "upload_max_filesize", "100M" );   ini_set( "post_max_size", "100M" );


ini_set( "session.save_handler", "files" ); session_start(); header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate("D, d M Y H:i ").' GMT');   header ('Expires: '.gmdate("D, d M Y H:i ").' GMT');   header ('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');   header ('Pragma: no-cache');

if ($_FILES['import']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK )           {
            $tmpName = $_FILES['import']['tmp_name'];
            $csvName = $_FILES['import']['name'];
            $mime = $_FILES['import']['type'];
            $validMimes = array('text/csv');


            if(!strpos($csvName, '.csv'))
            {
                $errMsg = ' [' . $csvName . '] is INVALID csv file (<i>csv only</i>)';
            }

            if ( is_uploaded_file($tmpName) && !isset($errMsg) ) // upload photo file then save author if uploaded file is VALID
            {
                // upload photo to server
                $filename = 'uploads/products/';

                $pathParts = pathinfo($csvName);

                $photoFile = _generateUniquePhoto($pathParts['extension']);

                //move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $filename . $photoFile);

                //chmod($filename . $photoFile, 0777);

                // save to database
                $fullfilename = $filename.$photoFile;
                //$this->data['University']['add_logo'] = $photoFile;

                $ftp_server = "XXXXX";
                $ftp_user_name = "XXXX";
                $ftp_user_pass = "XXXXX";


                // set up basic connection
                $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server); 

                // login with username and password
                $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass); 

                // check connection
                if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) 
                { 
                       echo "FTP connection has failed!";
                       echo "Attempted to connect to $ftp_server for user $ftp_user_name"; 
                       exit; 
                } else 
                {
                       //echo "Connected to $ftp_server, for user $ftp_user_name";
                }

                // upload the file
                $destination_file1 = "httpdocs/volhub/client/$fullfilename";
                $sourcefile1 = "$tmpName";
                $upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file1, $sourcefile1, FTP_BINARY);  // line 30

                // check upload status

                ftp_close($conn_id); }
```

Comment: Depending on whether PHP is running in Safe mode, you may have to set this in the ini file directly, rather than using `ini_set()` - Is it your own server? You may also want to consider one of the JS alternatives below as they're usually a better experience (progress bars, multiple simultaneous files, etc)

Comment: You'd better check the php.ini `upload_max_filesize and post_max_size `

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify those settings with `ini_set()` because they are [`PHP_INI_PERDIR`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php).

You will have to alter them in php.ini itself or with a (assuming Apache) `.htaccess` file. By the time your script starts to execute and `ini_set()` is called, PHP has already made the decision to accept or reject the request.

[See here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php) for more information regarding changing settings with a `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this too and couldn't find a solution and after a while i decided to use an javascript uploader with 'chunking' functionality. You can find the one I'm using on [plupload.com](http://www.plupload.com). It's quite easy to work with in my opinion.

Comment: So this is not really a solution, but more of a alternate way of doing what you are trying to do.